# Javascript creating SVG element using createElementNS sometimes returns a null

Tags: javascript, svg

The following code has a weird quirk:

```
function createSVG(){
    let svgarea = document.getElementById("svgarea");
    let svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
    svg.setAttribute("id", "my_svg");
    svg.setAttribute("width", "100%");
    svg.setAttribute("height", "100%");
    svgarea.appendChild(svg);
}
```

When I run call it from script when loading page or on window.onload, the script fails

```
"Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null"
```

at the

```
svgarea.appendChild(svg);
```

But it works normally if I call it from console. Is there a workaround for this? I suspect that the createElementNS somehow hangs before it gets to appending the result, but somehow it doesn't when calling from console.

Comment: When does this code run? Is it being run before `svgarea` exists?

Comment: You maybe calling `let svgarea = document.getElementById("svgarea");` before the HTML DOM is rendered. Could you reproduce this issue on a fiddle?

Comment: I don't know what fiddle is, but the svgarea is part of the html file the script is run on, and I call it via window.onload, so at least in theory it should run.

I also tried with setTimeout with one second (after window onload), and still same issue

Comment: Actually, the setTimeout worked, I just called it wrong. Now after window.onload, there is a function that sets timeout for 10ms, and now svg creates as it should

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the DOM Element `#svgarea` isn't there yet when you execute:
`let svgarea = document.getElementById("svgarea");`

When you execute the same statement from the console the DOM **is** there, ready

So you must delay execution of your `createSVG` function:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", createSVG);
```

You could also use the `load` Event but that fires later, after all content is loaded.

If you use `window.onload =`  you have to be 100% sure no later code will **override** it. `addEventListener` does what it says: it adds extra listeners

```js
setTimeout(createSVG);
```

Also does the trick, in cases where the Events have long past, and you can't use them. No time required because `setTimeout` will run after the Event Loop is done, thus any DOM creation will have happened.

If you want to create SVG, you can also use HTML notation:

```js
function createSVG(){
 document
  .getElementById("svgarea")
  .innerHTML=`<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' id='my_svg' width='100%' height='100%'></svg>`
}
```

Or, because innerHTML is render blocking, creates DOM nodes immediately:

```js
function createSVG(){
 let area = document.getElementById("svgarea");
 area.innerHTML=`<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' id='my_svg'></svg>`;
 let svg = area.querySelector("svg");
 svg.setAttribute("width","100%");
 svg.setAttribute("height","100%");
}
```

And don't forget you probably need a `viewBox` attribute on those SVGs